# What is this error: "Servicing stack shim unable to mark handle .... for delete-on-close, error STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE" error and how can I fix it?

Tags: windows

This error is related to the Windows operating system.
I have encountered several errors similar to the one mentioned in the title of the question, one of which was as follows:

```
00000003 Servicing stack shim unable to mark handle 1c0 ("\Device\Ramdisk{d9b257fc-684e-4dcb-ab79- 03cfa2f6b750}\Windows\temp\SSS_e91962693ad6d901010000000003e40a\msdelta.dll") for delete-on-close, error STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE
```

I want to know what is the meaning of this error and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a very common one, but either way lets try and break it down to understand it a bit better:

- "00000003" Is your Windows error code. In this case, it represents STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE
- "Servicing stack shim" refers to a component in Windows which manages updates and servicing of the OS.
- "unable to mark handle 1c0" seems to be suggesting that there is an issue when attempting to mark a specific resource (in your case `handle 1c0`) for deletion when it's closed.
- `"\Device\Ramdisk{d9b257fc-684e-4dcb-ab79- 03cfa2f6b750}\Windows\temp\SSS_e91962693ad6d901010000000003e40a\msdelta.dll"` is the path to the resource (I'm guessing this is your SSD or Hard Disk?) that is causing the problem.

You should try the following things first:

- Restart Your Computer
- Type "Troubleshoot" in your start menu search > Troubleshoot Settings. Then under additional troubleshooting choose windows update in the get up and running section. Proceed through the steps and see if that fixes the problem.

[image]

- Do a manual check for Windows Updates
- Check your disk for Disk Errors by typing `chkdsk /f` within the CMD application. You might need to restart your computer afterwards. If disk errors are found, then you may need to repair those errors or get a new drive.
- Do a system file check by typing `sfc /scannow` within the CMD application. If unrecoverable error are found you may need to re-install the OS should DISM repair fail.
- Run a DISM scan/repair by typing `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` within the CMD application.

Failing all of the above, you may have a third party app or some malware on the machine. In either case, if it were me I would copy off all my important data and re-install windows. So long as the drive is healthy, this should definitely make the problem go away.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I need a more accurate answer